# Should we use a digital low pass or high pass filter to remove sensor bias?

Tags: lowpass-filter, digital-filters, analog-to-digital, highpass-filter

Consider a continuous signal oversampled at, say $2 \;kHz$, and then system digital low pass filtered to a $100\;Hz$ frequency which is the control loop frequency. It is known that there is some bias in the signal since it is an accelerometer output.

1. If we use a discrete derivative with a discrete integral in series, will this remove (atleast some of) the DC bias in the signal?
2. Correspondingly it seems a better idea to use a high pass filter rather than a low pass filter although this will invite noise. Is a notch filter how people deal with accelerometer signals and should one go with a high pass approach in case of the unavailability of a notch filter (since the signal necessarily contains bias)?
3. Does the same logic hold if one designs the filter in the continuous domain?

Comment: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php

Comment: What's the application ? A control loop ? How big is the offset ? Sometimes the best thing to do is simply to ignore the offset

Comment: @MBaz thanks for the article. It seems a lot of is a duplicate of the author's [DC blocker algorithms paper](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT3205/Documents/TipsAndTricks/DCBlockerAlgorithms.pdf) by Yates and Lyons.

Comment: @Ben the application is a control loop which requires using the accelerometer estimate. I agree that it is not a bad idea to begin with, but the loop requires using the integral and double integral of the acceleration signal, thus leading to integration error. Further it is difficult to estimate *apriori* the offset since it will depend on operational conditions ranging from input vibration to temperature. To remove the bias indeed one can go to full-blown Kalman filters or data based debiasing (a better idea), but such suggestions miss the point of the desired *application oriented* response.

Comment: Try a dc-removal IIR filter. Include this filter in your control loop analysis to make sure your gain and phase margins are right.

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot for the comments. Could you please explain briefly, whether in an answer or comment why the [linked article](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php) talks about FIR filters and not IIR filters? Please ignore the naivety, if any, of my questions since I'm a controls person working on robotics and autonomous systems but have not had much exposure to DSP.

Comment: Unless the accelerometer estimate somehow parallels a direct position measurement of some sort, you're out of luck.  Your "should we use" question is immaterial, because without that independent position measurement, both choices are bad enough that "best" cannot apply to either.  I think you need to tell us more about the application.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks for the comment. The accelerometer outputs acceleration and one has to double integrate it to obtain position. The application is attempting to use the position feedback but is hindered by [integration drift](https://base.xsens.com/knowledgebase/s/article/How-do-I-calculate-position-and-or-velocity-from-acceleration-and-how-about-integration-drift-1605869707395) due to the noise and bias in the acceleration signal. The OP is trying to understand how one can remove the noise and bias. The paper linked earlier is essentially a derivative and integrator which makes sense.

Comment: Using a derivative then an integrator throws out the good with the bad.  You just can't get there from here, unless you start with something known.  Now, if you started at a known position and velocity (0,0 would be easiest) and held it for a while, you could capture those -- then when the position and velocity are no longer known, you could use the accelerometer for dead reckoning, for a time that depends on the quality of the accelerometer.  But starting from an unknown position and velocity would be useless.

Comment: That's why I asked what you're doing...

Comment: @TimWescott the system starts from known initial position, velocity and acceleration of 0 and will operate at *10 ms* cycles for a real-world time on the order of minutes. Say $n$ cycles post initialization, can you explain how the *dead reckoning* phrase you mentioned can help in improving the quality of the signal? Additionally doesn't the *fixed-point DC blocker* in the Yates and Lyons paper implement the cascaded differentiator and leaky-integrator (which presumably does not throw out the good with the bad, as you mentioned in your previous comment)?

Comment: The fact that it's on a machine of limited stroke, where the average velocity can be taken as zero, is an essential detail of the sort that should be *in the question*, not carelessly dropped into a comment someplace.  In no small part because it takes you firmly into that very small subset of no-position-sensor applications where an accelerometer may actually be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your application is a control loop. While I agree that a DC bias can impact the performance, I don't think this will cause your integrator to go to infinity. After all, a control loop has feedback so eventually the DC bias will cause your actuator to compensate for DC bias buildup.

[image]

Secondly, if you want to remove the DC offset. There are 2 standard techniques. One, calibrate your sensor and remove the DC offset from the measurements. Second technique, use a DC-removal IIR. Try to balance DC rejection and phase shift as the phase shift will take away some phase margin. Generally, we don't use FIR filters in control loops as they cause significant phase shift which could make your loop unstable.

Edit : If you filter the measured acceleration with a high-pass filter, you will not be able to follow a DC reference, only an AC reference. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the answer which summarizes the control issues cause by bias. I'm implementing a model based optimal control which looks like PD in implementation, so the same issues are true whether I action is added or not. I agree with the answer that  FIR filters in control loops introduce significant phase shifts. Does that mean that the schemes in the [Yates and Lyons paper](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT3205/Documents/TipsAndTricks/DCBlockerAlgorithms.pdf) is to be *used with caution* in the sense of accounting for the phase introduced by the investigated FIRs in that paper?

Comment: Would you also please let me know that it is accurate to say that, the *cascaded differentiator/integrator* $\equiv$ *fixed-point DC blocker* technique in the [Yates and Lyons paper](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT3205/Documents/TipsAndTricks/DCBlockerAlgorithms.pdf) is an IIR while the *general  linear-phase dc blocker* is a FIR?

Comment: the fixed-point DC blocker is an IIR while the general linear-phase dc-block is an FIR filter.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification about the filters in the linked paper. The edit adds value to the discussion, so I will respond to it and leave a request to the associate question. All [inertial sensors have biasing issues](https://base.xsens.com/knowledgebase/s/article/How-do-I-calculate-position-and-or-velocity-from-acceleration-and-how-about-integration-drift-1605869707395): 'Double integration of acceleration data to estimate position is inaccurate due to integration drift inherent with sensor noise and bias. When integrating data you will implicitly have to accept integration drift.' (1/2)

Comment: Double integration in closed-loops is not the same as double integration in open loops.

Comment: Since it is difficult to know what part of the sensor drift is due to noise and due to DC bias, especially without having access to ground truth data, one has to use both low and high pass filtering as in the *fixed-point DC blocker IIR* filter and tune offline and in-situ. This corresponds to dropping the DC and tracking (a part of, since we filter out some of the noise) the AC feedback. Is this description meaningful?

Comment: Generally you should a low-pass anti-aliasing filter. But you generally don't need a high-pass filter.

Comment: Although I agree that the double integration in CL or OL is distinct, it is practically certain that the sensor bias appears due to inaccuracies (noise and bias) in the sensor output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122728/discussion-between-kb314-and-ben).

Comment: The DC bias might drift, the gain might change with time and temperature, etc...

Usually control loops are more focused on stability than accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

> If we use a discrete derivative with a discrete integral in series, will this remove (atleast some of) the DC bias in the signal?

Yes (if your integrator starts at state 0).

Note that this is a CIC filter.

Also notice an offset should be present in your accelerator data, or you just got lost in space.

> Correspondingly it seems a better idea to use a high pass filter rather than a low pass filter although this will invite noise.

Well, seeing that by definition of "low-pass filter", the DC component remains untouched, this doesn't only seem to be a good idea, but mandatory.

> Is a notch filter how people deal with accelerometer signals and should one go with a high pass approach in case of the unavailability of a notch filter (since the signal necessarily contains bias)?

It depends on what people are doing for what purpose. My guess is you want to estimate something *from* your accelerometer observation. Maybe Kalman filters are what you're after?

> Does the same logic hold if one designs the filter in the continuous domain?

This has nothing to do with continuous or discrete time. So, yes.